# Uploading files with infyom generator

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload a file with laravel using the code generated by the infyom generator. The file seems to be uploaded but this is what is shown on the application when I view the report (C:\xampp\tmp\php7925.tmp). Provided below is the code for my application.

Thank you so much and really appreciate the help in this project.

rgds,

**Form**

```
<!-- Inf File Field --> 
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('inf_file', 'Attachments:') !!}
    {!! Form::file('inf_file') !!}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $infrastructure = $this->infrastructureRepository->create($input); 

    $file = $request->file('inf_file');

    $file = $request->inf_file;

    if ($request->hasFile('inf_file')){

        //
        if ($request->file('inf_file')->isValid()){

        }
    }

    Flash::success('Infrastructure saved successfully.');

    return redirect(route('infrastructures.index'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it.

```
    public function store(CreateinfrastructureRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    if ($request->hasFile('inf_file')){

        //Validate the uploaded file
        $Validation = $request->validate([

            'inf_file' => 'required|file|mimes:pdf|max:30000'
        ]);

        // cache the file
        $file = $Validation['inf_file'];

        // generate a new filename. getClientOriginalExtension() for the file extension
        $filename = 'Infras-' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // save to storage/app/infrastructure as the new $filename
        $InfrasFileName = $file->storeAs('infrastructure', $filename);

        $path = "/storage/app/public/".$InfrasFileName;
    }

    $input['inf_file'] = $path;

   $infrastructure = $this->infrastructureRepository->create($input);

    Flash::success('Infrastructure saved successfully. ' . $path);

    return redirect(route('infrastructures.index'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you display when  you view your records,

```
<!-- Inf File Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('inf_file', 'Attachements:') !!}
    <a download href="{{ asset($infrastructure->inf_file) }}">Download</a>
</div>
```